# Reducing the Dimension of Rectangular Assignment Matrices

Tags: counterexamples, matching-theory

> **Question:**
>
> Given a weighted complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}(U,V,E)$, $m^2\lt n$, are there any counter examples to the assumption, that the edges of the minimum weight maximal bipartite matching between the vertices of $U$ and $V$ is contained in $$\bigcup_{i,j=1}^{m} (u_i,v_{\pi_i (j)}),\quad \omega\left(u_i,v_{\pi_i(j)}\right)\le\omega\left(u_i,v_{\pi_i(j+1)}\right)$$
>   where $\pi_i(j)$ is a permutation, that renders the edges that are adjacent to $u_i$ sorted in non-decreasing order according their weights $\omega\left(u_i,v_{\pi_i(j)}\right)$?

Taking the question a bit further, how can a minimal set of edges be determined, that provably contains all edges of the minimum weight maximal bipartite matching?

The reason for asking is that in case no counter examples exist, the size of the assignment problem could atleast be reduced to $K_{m,m^2}(U,V',E')\subseteq K_{m,n}(U,V,E)$